# HTML and CSS - Custom Facebook Login Button

Tags: html, css, facebook

So I wanto to have my own facebook login button instead of the default one, I want [something like this](https://users.wix.com/signin). I'm pretty close, but I don't know what's missing, here is a snipet of what I've done so far:

```css
.login-facebook-text{
 align-items: center;
 border-bottom-color: rgb(59, 89, 152);
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-image-outset: 0px;
 border-image-repeat: stretch;
 border-image-slice: 100%;
 border-image-source: none;
 border-image-width: 1;
 border-left-color: rgb(59, 89, 152);
 border-left-style: solid;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-right-color: rgb(59, 89, 152);
 border-right-style: solid;
 border-right-width: 1px;
 border-top-color: rgb(59, 89, 152);
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 color: rgb(59, 89, 152);
 cursor: pointer;
 display: flex;
 font-family: HelveticaNeueW01-55Roma, HelveticaNeueW02-55Roma, HelveticaNeueW10-55Roma, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-stretch: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant-caps: normal;
 font-variant-east-asian: normal;
 font-variant-ligatures: normal;
 font-variant-numeric: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 height: 46px;
 justify-content: center;
 letter-spacing: normal;
 line-height: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 text-indent: 0;
 text-rendering: auto;
 text-shadow: none;
 text-transform: none;
 transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-property: background;
 transition-timing-function: ease;
 width: 239px;
 word-spacing: 0;
 writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.login-facebook-icon{
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgb(59, 89, 152);
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 cursor: pointer;
 display: flex;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 23px;
 font-stretch: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant-caps: normal;
 font-variant-east-asian: normal;
 font-variant-ligatures: normal;
 font-variant-numeric: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 height: 48px;
 justify-content: center;
 letter-spacing: normal;
 line-height: normal;
 text-align: center;
 text-indent: 0;
 text-rendering: auto;
 text-shadow: none;
 text-transform: none;
 width: 58px;
 word-spacing: 0;
 writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-facebook-icon">f</div>
<div class="login-facebook-text">Continue with Facebook</div>
```

The problems are:

- The elements are not in the same "row"
- There is no "on hover" animation
- The "f" letter is not as big as it is suppoused to

With that solved it would be good to go.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The elements are not on the same row because they're `<div>` elements which are block level. There's no "on hover" animation because you didn't make one. As for the `f`, increase the font size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the code below helps. I checked the Wix site, and I cleaned up the style you got from Wix. For the "f", Wix is using an icon font instead of regular text, you may want to get that from an icon provider like fontawesome.

```css
.login-button {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.login-button:hover {
  background: rgba(59, 89, 152, .1);
}

.login-facebook-icon {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 48px;
  width: 58px;   
  float: left;
}

.login-facebook-text {
  color: #3b5998;
  font-family: HelveticaNeueW01-55Roma, HelveticaNeueW02-55Roma, HelveticaNeueW10-55Roma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 239px;
  height: 46px;
  padding-left: 58px;
  border: 1px solid #3b5998;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-button">
  <div class="login-facebook-icon">f</div>
  <div class="login-facebook-text">Continue with Facebook</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I wil add an "f" from fontawesome then